# Simple C++/OOP inheritance

Tags: c++, oop

I need to know if this is possible

```
/* C++ Program to calculate the area and perimeter of rectangles using concept of inheritance. */

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class Rectangle
{
    protected:
       float length, breadth;
    public:
        Rectangle(): length(0.0), breadth(0.0)
        {
            cout<<"Enter length: ";
            cin>>length;
            cout<<"Enter breadth: ";
            cin>>breadth;
        }

};

/* Area class is derived from base class Rectangle. */
class Area : public Rectangle   
{
    public:
       float calc()
         {
             return length*breadth;
         }

};

/* Perimeter class is derived from base class Rectangle. */
class Perimeter : public Rectangle
{
    public:
       float calc()
         {
             return 2*(length+breadth);
         }
};

int main()
{
     cout<<"Enter data for first rectangle to find area.\n";
     Area a;
     cout<<"Area = "<<a.calc()<<" square meter\n\n";

     cout<<"Enter data for second rectangle to find perimeter.\n";
     Perimeter p;
     cout<<"\nPerimeter = "<<p.calc()<<" meter";
     return 0;
}
```

Taking into consideration the code above, is it possible to call a.calc() in main and that will do its code, but before we return have it call calc() from Parameter without creating Perimeter object inside Area or Rectangle

Thanks !

Comment: This makes little sense. But even if it made sense to use inheritance, you seem to have it backwards. Why would an area or a perimeter be rectangles?

Comment: This is just a sample and not the actual code I'm working on, just wanted to see it / explain it in a simpler way

Comment: @OliverCiappara: Unfortunately, this code is very abstract and what you're asking makes little sense.  I'd expect any and all answers we post here will have no relation to your actual code, unless your code is _very_ similar to this.

Comment: Why not run it yourself and see? :)

Comment: Holy unnecessary tabstops, Batman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can access C:Foo() from B:Foo() without creating C object in A or B ?

No.  Since `C::Foo()` is `private`, you can't access it from `B::Foo()` at all.

Comment: What if C:Foo() is public ?

Comment: It sounds like you're having trouble figuring out what question to ask, and that's why you're not getting the answers you want.  Since the other answers here address the first question you asked, I'm going to roll your question back.  If this question is radically different from what you're trying to ask, consider reading [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then post a new, better question.

Comment: Marking your answer as the correct one as its the closest answer to what I needed, don't understand the down votes, the question was never if the example makes sense, it was a question about accessing a method from a class that inherits the same base class as the one the call is made from, my mistake was that I explained my problem using a bad code example. I should have keep it abstract as with the edit I did. Thanks anyway for your help ended up working it out in a different way.

Answer (score 2):

The technical answer is that adding the function declaration:

```
virtual float calc() = 0;
```

to class `Rectangle` will allow you to call `a.calc()` in main but this is not a good case for inheritance. Think of "`A` inherits `B`" as "`A` is a `B`". It doesn't make sense to say "`Area` is a `Rectangle`" or "`Perimeter` is a `Rectangle`". It would make more sense to say something like "`Rectangle` is a `Shape`".

In the case you presented I would just add the functions `float getArea()` and `float getPerimeter()` to `Rectangle` and not use inheritance at all. You said this was just an example so maybe asking about your *actual* use case would yield better answers.

EDIT:

I just looked a little closer and saw that `a` is just a variable of type `Area` so the function declaration I mentioned is not needed *technically*.

Answer (score 1):

Always use the "is a" vs. "has a" comparison for deciding when to use inheritance.

```
A Rectangle *has a* perimeter
```

Therefore, perimeter should be a member variable of Rectangle (or in this case it could even just be a function).

However, with an example like

```
Honda *is a* car
```

Honda should inherit from the parent class car.